# What SAS modules do I need to run my code?

Tags: module, sas

I have a large collection of SAS programs. Currently, I have lots of SAS modules licensed and installed (I've checked which ones via %sasinstallreporter), but I'm not sure whether I need all of them.

How can I determine which modules I actually need in order to run all of my code? They're rather expensive and I don't want to pay for modules that I'm not going to use. Is there a list of procs / libname engines somewhere that are tied to specific SAS modules?

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but some brief searches didn't turn up anything obvious.

I have posted a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932840/what-sas-features-apart-from-procs-and-libname-engines-require-specific-sas-modu) regarding what other things I should be looking for in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st, get a list of all the procedures your code uses.  You can do this manually, or write a script in SAS/AWK/Perl to parse through your code.

Next, go to http://support.sas.com/documentation/ and search each for each of the unique Procedures.

For example, if I search for `PROC REG`, I get these results (http://support.sas.com/cdlsearch?charset=iso-8859-1&nh=25&ct=80000&qt=PROC+REG++&s1=3&searchterm=PROC+REG&sasreleasepart=&sasprodpart=&searchContains=).  You will see under the results `SAS/STAT(R)`, which tells you it is part of the SAS/STAT module.

You may also have things licensed that do not show up as `PROC XXX` in your code.  Things like SAS/Integration Technologies are used for running and connecting to a SAS server.  Talk to your SAS administrator about how those are used.

Happy hunting.

Comment: I think this looks promising, in conjunction with your approach:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/allprodsproc/63875/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003178332.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you are paying for SAS, I would say send this question to SAS technical support, they should be able to help you with a list.

I don't think there is a definative list of modules and associated PROCS on the web.

Regards,
Vasilij