# What SAS features apart from procs and libname engines require specific SAS modules?

Tags: module, sas

This is a follow-up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920551/what-sas-modules-do-i-need-to-run-my-code).

It seems feasible for me to write a script that parses my collection of SAS code and finds all the `proc` and `libname` statements, and then I can look up which modules those require. If I go with that approach, what other things should I be looking for in my code that would require additional SAS modules?

Answer (score 0):

- `rsubmit` and `signon` statements require SAS/CONNECT
- `connect to` clauses in `proc sql` may require various 'SAS/ACCESS interface to XYZ' modules